# PHP Serialization Will not work correctly

Tags: php, oop, serialization

I am developing and doing all the testing on a local machine using PHP Version 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 version. The host machine is PHP Version 5.2.15.

All the seriliaze arguments are identical.

The problems is when i try to login the user on my test local machine I do the following:

```
$user->getByUserId($results['id'], $db); 
$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
```

which retrieved and serialize the user and I just load it back whenever I detect that a session exists:

```
$user->LoadFromObject(unserialize($_SESSION['user']));
```

This works perfectly on my test machine. Just transfered the files on the host to see if I can get a beta version out but I keep on getting :

> Warning: unserialize() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in /home/gamerent/public_html/beta/includes/header.php
>   on line 19

i have noticed that if i echo the `$_SESSION['user']` in both system the test will indeed display me the serialized one but the main one will just show me the object and will not serialize the `$user`.

UPDATE :

OK after some testing ..... 
i have seen that if i dump the session before initializing the user as

```
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
$user = new User();
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
```

it will display the session serialized correctly.
Exactly after that it will display the String of the sessions

My User doesnt do anything excpet init with default values

```
function User() {
        $this->userId = 0;
        $this->firstname = "Guest";
        $this->password = "";
        include_once('includes/generalUtils.php');
        $this->generalUtils = new generalUtils();
        include_once('includes/utils.php');
        $this->utils = new utils();
    }
```

Comment: So serialize($user); is returning $user on the host machine?

Comment: Side note: It' PHP 5.x. Use __construct as identifier for constructor. Using class name for that is deprecated.

Comment: And really... look into class autoloading - having these includes in the constructor is ugly.

Comment: @Mchi will do for the __constructor , i had that in mind had no idea it was depr.
Also .... where can i get those autoloading ? i was looking for something similar didnt manage to find anythin.

Comment: Could you check that register_globals is off on both machines? I think, if you have it on, you are registering a session variable by assigning to $_SESSION.

Comment: @AndreKr
Production Machine : 
register_argc_argv On On
register_globals On On
register_long_arrays On On
Test Machine : 
register_argc_argv Off Off
register_globals Off Off
register_long_arrays Off Off

so this should be the reason why it doesnt hold my sessions !

Comment: @stevoo - See http://th2.php.net/spl_autoload_register for info on registering an autoloader.  Doing things this way makes it easier to store things in the session as well; skip serializing stuff yourself and let PHP do it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable register_globals on the production machine. Otherwise you are registering a session variable by assigning to $_SESSION['user']. Check [these notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php).